# Pass multiple state values to child component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to send two state elements as props and I need to send **list** and **menu** as one var.

My **getInitialState** function is like;

```
getInitialState:function(){
    return{
      list:['Breakfast: 9.00', 'Lunch: 12.00', 'Dinner: 18.00'],
      menu:['Kahvaltılık Sebzeli Sucuk, Soslu Zeytin, PeynirBal', 'Tel şehriyeli Çorba, Patates Kızartması, Uzun Makarna, Renkli Salata (tarifimdeki)', 'Patatesli Sigara Böreği, Mercimek köftesi, Elmalı Kurabiye']
    }
  }
```

And **var** is;

```
var list = this.state.list;
list = list.map(function(item, index){
  return(
    <ListItem item={item} key={index} onClick={this.handleVisibility}/>
  );
}.bind(this));
```

I tried to do that as;

```
var list = this.state.list;
list = list.map(function(item, index){
  return(
    <ListItem item={item} menu={this.state.menu} key={index} onClick={this.handleVisibility}/>
  );
}.bind(this));
```

I also tried this but not working;

```
var menu = this.state.menu;
var list = this.state.list;
list = list.map(function(item, index, menu){
  return(
    <ListItem item={item} menu={menu} key={index} onClick={this.handleVisibility}/>
  );
}.bind(this));
```

But it returns **undefined**

Comment: `this` is the scope of your function.

Comment: Ok but how can I go out of my function to call .state.menu? @JamesDonnelly

Comment: Store it in a variable like you've done with your list or use a lambda function instead.

Comment: why u r using map? ListItem is a component in which u want to pass both list and menu ?? and who returns `undefined` ?

Comment: Idk another way to store state into a variable man. I'm beginner to ReactJS. When I try to send menu as props to ListItem component, it returns undefined.  @MayankShukla

Comment: @BurakULU will help you, you want to pass the menu to each listitem ?

Comment: I want to pass menu and list into ListItem and send both of them as props @MayankShukla

Comment: you don't want the loop ?

Comment: What happens if I don't want the loop? Will it send just first item of menu state array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
<ListItem list = {this.state.list} menu={this.state.menu} onClick={this.handleVisibility}/>
```

Now in `ListItem` you can access them by `this.props.list` and `this.props.menu`.

**Update:**

```
var list = this.state.list;
list = list.map((item, index) => {
    return(
        <ListItem item={item} menu={this.state.menu} key={index} onClick={this.handleVisibility.bind(this)}/>
    );
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I have a error. I put your solution to out of map function and it logically says that item and index are not found. Sorry I tried your solution just before.

Comment: just remove the item and index, that is not required, item was the each element of array and index was its index, now you are passing the complete array to child in props. why u want to use that item and index ?

Comment: I want to use item and index to get the clicked item in other component. I can't follow which item is clicked without item and index and yes, still I'm trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: check the updated answer, it will work surely. Each ListItem, menu is passed as props you can access by this.props.menu. let me know if it didn't work or u face any issue in this